# Vectors and Forces problem

Tags: forces

I have a question that I  think I have an idea of how to answer but I am unsure can someone please verify for me? Here goes:

Here is a box and a force (vector say, F1) of 10 N in the positive direction. If the box is 3kg, what is the direction and size of another force (say F2), that would be needed to give the box an acceleration of + 2m/s^2

[image: Box and Force]

Also I think it should be in the negative direction since the required acceleration should be  +2m/s^2 Should this approach be right? What would be your answer for mass and direction?

Comment: If only $F_1$ acts on the box, what is the acceleration?

Comment: Is friction involved at all?

Comment: That is all the information the questions give to me. The magnitude if F1 is 10N

Comment: So force and acceleration are related by what? Do you know about Newton's Laws?

Comment: You know the force and mass and you want acceleration. So what famous equation relates force $F$, mass $m$, and acceleration $a$?

Comment: force is mass time acceleration. So do I just set 10N=3 x acceleration then solve for acceleration.

Comment: That's the first step, yes. So rearrange that to find the acceleration...

Comment: So would the size of F2 be 100N (since 10/3=a, and the mass of the box is 3)?

Comment: No. So what we know so far: a force of 10 N pushing a 3 kg box will give it an acceleration of +10/3 m/s$^2$. But we want that acceleration to be 2 m/s$^2$. So how much do we need to decelerate it by?

Comment: 10/3ms^-2 is 4/3ms^-2 away from 2. So we Need to decelerate by 4/3

Comment: That's right. So what force do we need to apply to a 3 kg object to accelerate it (in the negative direction) by 4/3 m/s$^2$?

Comment: -4N or 4N I believe I'm unsure

Comment: The magnitude is indeed 4 N but since it is acting in the negative direction, the force is -4 N.

Comment: Thanks much everyone who contributed. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi jdreamin. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's Second Law is not simply $F=ma$, it's $$\sum F_{ext}=ma.$$ The sum of the external forces on a body is what results in the net acceleration. Thus, if we assume that $F_2$ acts in the positive direction, we have $$F_1+F_2=ma,$$ or after rearranging, $$F_2=ma-F_1.$$ If the value you get once the numbers are plugged in is negative, that just means that the actual force is in the opposite direction to what was initially assumed.

Comment: I am going to assume that the downvote comes from giving too much away, so I modified my answer (lemon)

Comment: You can rollback the edit, that most likely isn't why there was a downvote.